# sql query to get the number of cooperating

Tags: sql

I need help with SQL query. I have this join table, with 22486 rows.

idPerson are people working on movie, pesonType '1' is actor and '2' is director. I need get director and actor and number of their cooperating on movies.

For example, director idPeroson = 3 work with actor idPerson = 14 on 2 movies.

```
| idFilm | idPerson | peronType |
+---------+---------+--------+
| 1       | 14      | 1      |
| 1       | 3       | 2      |
| 1       | 34      | 1      |
| 2       | 3       | 2      |
| 2       | 14      | 1      |
+---------+---------+--------+
```

I'm going crazy from that. Thank you very much. And sorry for bad english

Comment: which RDBMS u r using? u want to do a self join?

Comment: @bonCodigo: what's an *u r*?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: it is `select right('you',1) + ' ' + substring('are',2,1)` ... :)

Comment: @Kaf good one :D yes I meant to say `are you`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  d.idPerson AS Director,
  p.idPerson AS Actor,
  (SELECT COUNT(p2.idfilm)
   FROM Persons p2
   INNER JOIN Persons d2  ON p2.idFilm = d2.idFilm 
   AND d2.peronType = 2
   WHERE p2.peronType = 1
     AND p2.idperson = p.idperson
     AND d2.idperson = d.idperson ) Counts
FROM Persons p
INNER JOIN Persons d  ON p.idFilm = d.idFilm 
                     AND d.peronType = 2
WHERE p.peronType = 1;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0f52/4)

This will give you:

```
| DIRECTOR | ACTOR | COUNTS |
-----------------------------
|        3 |    14 |      2 |
|        3 |    34 |      1 |
```

Answer (score 2):

A more effective way to have the same good result will be :

```
SELECT
  D.idPerson Director,
  P.idPerson Actor,
  count(1) NBFilm
FROM       Persons D
INNER JOIN Persons P ON D.idFilm = P.idFilm 
WHERE P.peronType = 1
  AND D.peronType = 2
GROUP BY  D.idPerson, P.idPerson
```

So you will have only one inner join. sub queries in select can be very cost effective.

Comment: Count with Group By, i didn't know it existed (shame on me). Looks really effective !

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the person working on number of films,

```
select idperson,count(distinct idfilm) NoOfFilms,
case when persontype=2 then 'Director' else 'Actor' end Profession
from table1
group by idperson
```

[**SQL_LIVE_DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61fd8/1)

Sample Output:

```
    IDPERSON    NOOFFILMS   PROFESSION
        3             2      Director
       14             2      Actor
       34             1       Actor
```